# Insert a MS Office document on VB.NET Picturebox at Runtime

Tags: vb.net

I am Migrating the code from VB^ to Vb.Net. I want to insert MS office docs like word file or excel file in the PictureBox in "Vb.net". I think in vb6 they have used `Microsoft.Office.Interop`.  What can I do in Vb.Net? Please Reply if u can help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Microsoft's WebBrowser Control](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243058/en-us), that should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Alexander... But what I want to do is to insert a new blank MS Office file on the PictureBox in Vb.Net. On button click the file should be opened and should look like a Normal exce/word file "on the PictureBox"

Comment: Do you want just a preview, or a full running Word/Excel application inside that PictureBox for the user to work in it?